# Facebook permissions to post to pages only

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We're working on an app allowing users to make scheduled posts to their pages. But, we don't need to post anything to their walls.

The existing scope is: `email, manage_pages, publish_actions, read_insights`

Is there any way to get rid of [this prompt](http://cl.ly/image/3L0X2h1v202B)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really possible at the moment (and it should based on your scenario)

All actions that require posting use the `publish_actions` permission. So there isn't a way to separate user from page here.

Internally as long as you use the page access token (not the user token) you are guaranteed not to accidentally post to the user's wall.

You should file a bug as a feature request https://developers.facebook.com/bugs